# Drawing two streamgraph with different data in one canvas

Tags: processing, stream-graph

I am new to processing.js and trying to create streamgraph based on the open source codes provided here https://github.com/jsundram/streamgraph.js/blob/master/src/streamgraph.pjs.
I would like to know how can I go about drawing two streamgraph with different dataset (one at the top of the screen and the other one at bottom of the screen)in one canvas.